# How to show the current user information using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to get the user information by id. Its alerting fine.
But I have to print the user information in the html page.

**Source:**

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="GetUserName();" id="user">aaaa</a>
<script language="javascript">
        function GetUserName()
        {
            var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            alert(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%, %ComputerName%, %USERDOMAIN%"));

        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output Should be:

```
 <div id="user">User Information: <span id="userinfo"></span></div>
```

**User Information:** "user name, computer name, user domain"

How can i print the information in div or others?

Comment: Rather than alerting, why not just write the result to div.html()?

Comment: use can use innerHTML property of getElementById `document.getElementById("userinfo").innerHTML = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%, %ComputerName%, %USERDOMAIN%")`

Comment: Do you realize that is going to work on a very small subset of browsers?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

just change the inner HTML of the span. Put below statement in place of alert.

```
document.getElementById("userinfo").innerHTML = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%, %ComputerName%, %USERDOMAIN%");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerHTML` property, it sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="user">User Information: <span id="userinfo"></span></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("userinfo").innerHTML = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%, %ComputerName%, %USERDOMAIN%")
```

Comment: thank you. But, It could not print in the mentioned id and its not working in the chrome.                                                                                                '<div id="user">User Information: <span id="userinfo"></span></div>
<script language="javascript">
  function GetUserName()
        {
  var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  document.getElementById("userinfo").innerHTML = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%, %ComputerName%, %USERDOMAIN%");
        }
  
</script>'

Comment: @Darious what do you mean could not print in the mentioned id?? What is the difference between my answer and the answer that you have chosen as correct??